# Saving URL in Resource

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I am giving URL in NSTextField and it loads in web view by hitting action button.

```
-(IBAction)showPage:(id)sender{
    [[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString.stringValue]]];
}
```

Every time when in run application i need to give URL.

Is there any way to save this URL somewhere e.g Package contents (Resources) that whenever i run my app it should take previously given url automatically and textfield should be available as blank to give new one.

Thanks

Comment: Now I am following you :P . You are asking / learning step by step here :)

Comment: Yes off course, best answers are available here. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a great place to make use of [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and storing something in there.

E.G.:  `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setURL: yourURL forKey: @"someURLIWantToPresent"];`

You can use the "`setURL: forKey`" API if you want to save the raw NSURL, or "`setObject: forKey:`" if you want to save the actual string that makes up the URL.

To load this into your your text field, it can be as easy as doing this in your view controller's "`viewDidLoad:`" method:

```
urlString.stringValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"someURLIWantToPresent"];
```

And upon hitting the action button, save off the URL via something like:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: urlString.stringValue forKey: @"someURLIWantToPresent"];
```

Comment: Actually i am new to programming can you please elaborate your answer little bit - Thanks

Comment: thanks, it helped me, can i retrieve values which are saved in [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]?? and can i use this value for creating shortcut of my simple app (with webview) with that particular URL which is saved in NSUserDefaults?? just like firefox Prism..

Comment: Yes, whatever you save in NSUserDefaults is available to your application later on.  Think of it as a simple per-application preferences store.

Answer (score 0):

when you navigate the page at that time save the data in `NSUserDefaults` .

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:textfield.text forKey:@"textfield value"];
    [defaults synchronize];
and re assign the textfield value in viewWillAppear method.

NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   textfield.text= [defaults  valueForKey:@"textfield value"];
```

or

other wise take an global string and assign the string value to `textFiled` and Vice Versa.

Answer (score 0):

try `NSUserDefaults`

Save the URL into the defaults:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YourURLHere"] forKey:@"MyURL"];
```

When the button is pressed, you can retrieve the URL (or you might want to set the text field on `viewWillAppear:animated`)

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"MyURL"];
```

[NSUserDefaults Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)